# Can a single TIdHTTPServer component handle http and https request in the same time?

Tags: delphi, http, indy

I'm using a TIdHTTPServer component, so far is working fine, but when I added SSL support using this code

```
  SSLHandler:= TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'foo.pem';
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'foo.pem';
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'foo.pem';
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;

  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 1;
  SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer,sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert,sslvrfClientOnce];

  idHttpServer1.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
  IdHTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 80;  
  IdHTTPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port := 443;       
  IdHTTPServer1.Active := True;
```

The server only process https requests and if I send a http request  this exception is thrown

`Error accepting connection with SSL. error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request`

The question is : I can use a single TIdHTTPServer component to process the http and https requests? if the answer is Yes how this can be done?  If the answer is No, I must create two TIdHTTPServer instances one for http and another for https?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single `TIdHTTPServer` for both HTTP and HTTPS.

If you are using Indy 9, then it has a bug where all client connections will have SSL **enabled** by default when they connect to the server.  To work around that, use the server's `OnConnect` event to manually turn **off** SSL if the connection is not on port 443, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  if AThread.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port <> 443 then
    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket(AThread.Connection.Socket).PassThrough := True;
end;
```

If you are using Indy 10, then that bug was fixed, so all client connections will have SSL **disabled** by default, so you can either:

1. use the `OnConnect` event to turn **on** SSL if the connection is on port 443, eg:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
   begin
     if AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port = 443 then
       TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.Socket).PassThrough := False;
   end;
   ```
2. (preferred) use the new `TIdHTTPServer.OnQuerySSLPort` event to tell the server which port should use SSL or not, eg:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1QuerySSLPort(APort: TIdPort; var VUseSSL: Boolean);
   begin
     VUseSSL := (APort = 443);
   end;
   ```